# My 2015 Subaru Impreza hesitates when turning after stopping?

Tags: transmission, cvt-transmission

Impreza requires full throttle when coming out of a driveway and turning. It never does this at any other time. Dealer told me it was a problem caused by the CVT transmission? This can be really dangerous when trying to join other traffic. Anyone had this problem?

Comment: what do you mean full throttle? Are you saying "from a stop, pedal to the floor acceleration with the wheel turned enough to do 90° turn"?

Comment: We borrowed a Subaru XV for a month (wasn't new - had a whole 600 miles on it) while one of our cars was being repaired. It had exactly the same issue - which can be frightening when trying to come out of a side street. We told the dealer about it, and their response was "yeah, they do that sometimes"...). There *should* be a software update available for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you have to push the gas pedal down more than half way, even when the wheel is completely fully turned, bring the vehicle to a dealer for repair.

That is not normal.

How many miles do you have on it? Looks like your warranty is 6yrs/60k miles.

Have you had any software updates performed on the vehicle?